# tsocks alternative for windows

Tags: windows, linux, putty

i use in linux the following command to create a tunnel

```
tsocks ssh -n -f -N -L 1081:142.51.6.42:22 admin@142.51.10.36
```

after which i use

```
ssh root@localhost -p 1081
```

is it possible to replicate the same in windows using putty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY has ssh tunneling support (including SOCKS4/5 support). though in your case you could simply run a first PuTTY connection to set up a static port forward.

If you really need a tsocks (ie. socksify) alternative, you can try [WideCap](http://widecap.com/), and set up a Dynamic port forward in PuTTY